# Java class inheritance override List field

Tags: java, list, inheritance, avro, lombok

I am facing a problem, I have a **avro generated** class A and another B defined like this :

```
class A {
    String code;
}

class B {
     String someString;
     List<A> codes;
}
```

And custom classes that extends the two generated classes, described before, like these :

```
class CustomA extends A {
    String type;
}

class CustomB extends B {
    List<CustomA> codes;
}
```

It works if I remove the **List<>** but I realy need it.
For the getters/setters, I use **lombok @Data** annotations.

Do somebody have a solution to work around?

I suppose that the same problème will arrived with a **Map<>**, so I need a solution too.

Thanks for your answers.

[EDIT]
So I will give more concrete examples with these two screenshot below.

[Here my classes declarations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmP14.png). As I said before, classes A and B (here User and ToDoItem) are generated classes by an avro schema, so I cannot modify/write in it. [Here the compilation errors I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhVMI.png).

Comment: "_It works if I remove the List<>_" What exactly does not work if you leave it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics. Like

```
class B<T extends A> {
   List<T> codes;
}

class CustomB extends B<CustomA> {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make that work is generics, as [@kiv_apple pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021945/10026074). 
With your generated code, instances of `CustomB` may always contain references to `A` instances in the `codes` list. There is no way you can restrict that without touching the class definition of `B`.

As this is not possible in your case, you have to find a workaround. One way to go could be defining a custom, differently named getter (without Lombok) that only returns those elements of `codes` that are instances of `CustomB`.